# Why remainders of division give base expression?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$214 = 3 · 71 + 1$

$71 = 3 · 23 + 2$

$ 23 = 3 · 7 + 2 $

$7 = 3 · 2 + 1 $

$2 = 3 · 0 + 2$

As a result, to obtain a base $3$ expansion of $214$, we take the remainders of divisions and we get that $(214)_{10} = (21221)_3$.

Question: why do the remainders give base $3$ expansion of $214$? And why order is from bottom to top?

Comment: Try it on a base 10 number.

Comment: Because that's the definition of a base number representation.  Dividing gives a unique remainder so we *can* use remainders to uniquely express numbers.  If we do so, the result is a base representation. This is how base 10 works.  We use base 10, rather than roman numerals because it is more efficient and expendable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of the base $3$ numeration,

$$|abcde|_3=a\cdot3^4+b\cdot3^3+c\cdot3^2+d\cdot3+e.$$

Divide by $3$ to get the remainder $e$ and the quotient

$$a\cdot3^3+b\cdot3^2+c\cdot3+d.$$

Divide by $3$ to get the remainder $d$ and the quotient

$$a\cdot3^2+b\cdot3+c.$$

Divide by $3$ to get the remainder $c$ and the quotient

$$a\cdot3+b.$$

Divide by $3$ to get the remainder $b$ and the quotient

$$a.$$

Divide by $3$ to get the remainder $a$ and the quotient

$$0.$$

Comment: To get remainder $e$ and quotient, $3.(a3^2+b3^1 +c) + d= 3n+d $ where $n=(a3^2+b3^1 +c)$ and same for others?

Comment: @user420742: yep, but you are already at step two.

Answer (score 0):

$$214=(((((((2\times 3)+1)\times 3)+2)\times 3)+2)\times 3)+1$$